# Scrapy, scraping elements only visible during runtime

Tags: javascript, python, html, scrapy

I am new to Scrapy, HTML and Javascript. I am trying to source a list of all branches and agents for our agency from the website. Most of the information I need can be extracted from an AJAX result: [www.tysonprop.co.za/ajax/agents/?branch_id=[id]](http://www.tysonprop.co.za/ajax/agents/?branch_id=%5Bid%5D)

The challenge is two fold:

1. The branch names displayed on the website (https://www.tysonprop.co.za/agents/) are contained within span elements not visible when viewing the page source. This means that Scrapy cannot find the information. For example, "Tyson Properties Fourways Office" should in theory be located at: xpath(//div[@id="select2-result-label-76"]/span[@class="select2-match"]/text())   [![see inspect element][1]][1])
2. The AJAX call requires the branch-id. I can't figure out how the page translates the branch name selected in the drop-down to a branch id to intercept the logic. I.e. how do I extract a list of branch names with corresponding ID's?

I have done an extensive web search without much success. Any help would be appreciated.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kjk8.png

```
class TysonSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'tyson_spider'

    def start_requests(self):
        url = 'https://www.tysonprop.co.za/ajax/agents/?branch_id=25'
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):

        agent = Agent()

        json_data = json.loads(response.text)

        branch_id = json_data['branch']['id']
        branch_name = json_data['branch']['branch_name']
        branch_tel = json_data['branch']['get_dialable_telephone_number']

        # Loop through all of th agents
        agent_list = json_data['agents']

        for key in range(len(agent_list)):
            agent['id'] = agent_list[key]['id']
            agent['branch_id'] = branch_id
            agent['branch_name'] = branch_name
            agent['branch_tel'] = branch_tel
            agent['privy_seal_url'] = agent_list[key]['privy_seal_url']
```

Related question: [Scrapy xpath not extracting div containing special characters <%=](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64023855/scrapy-xpath-not-extracting-div-containing-special-characters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look into the page source, you can see the branch id's and names are present in the HTML, and located under 'name="agent_search"'.
With the logic below you go through the different branches and get their id & name:

```
branches_xpath = response.xpath('//*[@name="agent_search"]//option')
for branch_xpath in branches_xpath[1:]:  # skip first option as that one is empty
  branch_id = branch_xpath.xpath('./@value').get()
  branch_name = branch_xpath.xpath('./text()').get()
  print(f"branch_id: {branch_id}, branch_name: {branch_name}")
```

Comment: Thank you Wim, I missed that. Still learning! Appreciate the help